# trailhead - We could not find the Apex class HouseService.cls. Make sure to follow the instructions in this step to create and deploy

Tags: salesforce

I am writing business logic in apex

these are the steps i have followed

1. In Visual Studio Code, under force-app/main/default, right-click classes and select SFDX: Create Apex Class.
2. In the Visual Studio Code Command Palette, name the class HouseService. Click Enter | Enter.
3. Replace the contents of the file with the following code.

```
public with sharing class HouseService {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<House__c> getRecords() { 
        try {
            // Create a list of House records from a SOQL query
            List<House__c> lstHouses = [
                SELECT
                   Id,
                   Name,
                   Address__c,
                   State__c, 
                   City__c,
                   Zip__c
                   FROM House__c
                   WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
                   ORDER BY CreatedDate
                   LIMIT 10
                ];
                  return lstHouses;
        }
        // Code to handle exception
        catch (Exception e) {
           throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

4. Save this file.
5. Right-click HouseService.cls and select SFDX: Deploy Source to Org. You see a confirmation message that the Apex class successfully deployed to the org. Deploying your code also compiles it on the server.
6. Create a new file named dreamhouseappTest.apex in the scripts/apex folder.
7. Replace the contents of the file with the following code: System.debug(HouseService.getRecords());
8. Click Code Lens Execute Anonymous Apex

I have tried running this code , also code ran successfully

but when i am verifying step in trailhead and try to submit

i have been facing following error and not able to submit.

We could not find the Apex class HouseService.cls. Make sure to follow the instructions in this step to create and deploy HouseService.cls.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the org VS is saving to is the same org (playground) trailhead is checking the challenge in? in VS you can open the org (`sfdx force org open`), compare that with what trailhead's "Launch" button does

Can you see the class in the org in Setup -> Apex Classes?